# Django datetime field compered to now

Tags: django, datetime, django-models, field

Please help.

I have this in my models.py

```
class Notificator(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()
    bought_from = models.ManyToManyField(VigneteSeller, blank=True)
    start_alert = models.DateTimeField()
    start_notifying_me = models.IntegerField(default=20)
    def save(self):
        d = timedelta(days=self.start_notifying_me)
        if not self.id:
            self.start_alert = self.end_date - d
            super(Notificator, self).save()

    @classmethod
    def starter(cls):
        ready = []
        if timezone.now() >= cls.start_alert:
            ready.append(cls.headline)
        return ready

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

All I want is to collect all instanceses from "start_alert" field compare it with timezone.now and return it with the starter function, and I am stuck.

Comment: I am getting this Error ---> TypeError("'>=' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'DeferredAttribute'")

Comment: `classmethod` has no purpose here. Just use a regular method and use `self` to access attributes of the instance.

Answer (score 0):

This will return all instances with a start time greater than now

```
from datetime import datetime

Notificator.objects.filter(start_alert__gte=datetime.now())
```

Comment: Hi, Blind Rabit I tried this as well and doesn`t work.

Comment: Are you trying to do with the data? it might help if you show your view.py as well

Comment: Hallo Blind Rabit, I am not using it in views.py. I just wanna return it to another module, which is gonna the starter function.

Comment: I didn`t ask, but I am supposed to use this code in models.py. Is it correct to use in models.py?

Comment: I'd Suggest not, I think you'd be best using the code shown above to create a queryset of the Notificator model and work with that.

Comment: All done. Thank you Blind Rabit. Now I have other problem. I looking for a Heroku alternative for more then 2 free DYNOS. Any suggestions?

Comment: if my answer has helped please can you upvote? I guess upgrade to hobby dev and paid for them.